# Ruby on Rails, datatable. multiple records for one user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am a bit confused about creating and inserting data in the table.

For example, I have user-table, where all users are saved. A payment-table should save all payments made by user A. The payments will not be updated. Once user A is registered, he fills up a form where he types his payments and there are saved and nothing more. ( I know it sounds strange but my database is based on statistical analysis of the files. Once a file is loaded, analysis is done and the data from the analysis (simple numbers) have to be stored. So pro file there are about 1000 numbers to be stored and nothing will be updated). Reference key is user's id.
So, it should be something like this:

```
class PaymentsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :payments do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.float   :sum
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is that i do not understand how I can save 10 payemnts of user A only if I specified t.float :sum only one time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to make entry of each of payments made by a user and you want to sum those payments then your current way is wrong.

you can create table of payments like this,

class PaymentsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
    create_table :payments do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.float   :amount
    end
    end

so if you sum this amount column by query like

user_payment = Payment.where(:user_id=>params[:user_id)).first.sum(&:amount)

Comment: sorry, I edited my question. I want to save all payments made by user and not the sum of them. Example, user A payed yesterday 235 dollars, and today 10 dollars. So, in payments table it should stay: user A, 235, 10

Comment: there are main 2 ways to do that. either you can create new record for each payment or you can make an amount field string and store amount value in a string by comma separated but if you want data on a date/day base then better create new entry for each payment

Comment: m... ok. will it make difference if I say, that the payments done by user will never change. I mean, the table will never be updated for this specific user. Once a new user registrated, his payments(about 1000 payments) are loaded to the database and saved. User will do no new payments. (I know it looks strange and absurd but my databasa is based on statistical analysis and once the file(user in this example) is loaded, analysis is done and numbers (payments) are stored in the table. So, no new numbers(payments) will be produced.

Comment: actually i don't understand what is your actual requirement. can you please elaborate in another way ? once you said that you want to keep payment data on day basis and now you don't want to update payments table for specific user. really, i don't understand your last comment.

Comment: I edited my question. Day basis was just example that I do not want to store the sum, but all payments. And once the user is registreated, he fills up what payments he has done and those numbers have to be saved in the table. There is no update of the table. Once the users have writen his payments, there are stored and the user cannot change them or update.

Comment: i understood. user will do his/her payments just after registration and will be used for analysis purpose. so you can create new record for each user's payments or you just keep user amount in a comma separated way. if there are like 1000 payments then keep it comma separated. otherwise, if you create new entry(say 1000 entries) for each payment, then it is worst because, all 1000 entries will have duplicated values in each column except payment amount. what you say ? and keep in mind that your float sum column will be unnecessary here.

Comment: I did not quite understand your last sentence. I load a file A(containing some numbers/text and blabla), file will be analyzed, the result of this analysis are 1000 numbers and I have to store them. Once file B is loaded and analyzed, it will have it's own 1000 numbers. And the number of files is about 10.000 or more. So, it is better to store those 1000 result numbers in a string, but will I be able to access those numbers after that and to use them in some calculations? (I guess there is something like split function to separate the entries by comma)

Comment: yes, you can manipulate those comma separate values using split function.